# Isomorphism of the $K$-Algebras $K[T] \otimes_K F \cong F[T]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

> Let $F$ be a field extension of $K$. I would like to prove that $$\varphi: K[T] \otimes_K F \rightarrow F[T]$$ is an isomorphism of $K$-Algebras.

What I got/tried so far:

Since the normal product of two polynomials over a field is again a polynomial over this field, $K \subseteq F$, and the tensor product of two $K$-Algebras is again a $K$-Algebra, I know that $F[T]$ and $K[T] \otimes_K F$ are $K$-Algebras.

I claim that the isomorphism is $\varphi(f\otimes_Ka)=f*a$, where $*$ is the multiplication in $F$ resp. $K$. Let's first check, wether this $\varphi$ is a $K$-Algebra homomorphism. Let be $f\otimes a$, $g \otimes b$ $\in K[T] \otimes_K F$ and $\lambda \in K$.

1. $\varphi(\lambda(f \otimes a))=\varphi((\lambda * f)\otimes a) = \lambda * f * a = \lambda * \varphi(f \otimes a)$ by the properties of the tensor product and my definition of $\varphi$.
2. $\varphi((f\otimes a)+(g\otimes b)) = ??? = f*a + g*b =\varphi(f \otimes a)+\varphi(g \otimes b)$
3. $\varphi((f\otimes a)*(g\otimes b)) = ??? = f*g*a*b= f*a * g*b =\varphi(f \otimes a)*\varphi(g \otimes b)$

Is this the correct track and if yes, could someone help me with the questionmarks, since I am pretty sure I am not alloud to do this componentwise?

I also need to show, that $\varphi$ is bijective. But if I am honest I have no clue why my $\varphi$ should be surjective or injective.... That's why I think my hole idea is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct. Nevertheless, elements of $K[T]\otimes_K F$ do **NOT** have the form $f\otimes a$, but they are finite sums of such things. To prove that there is a $\varphi$ as you want (ie that it is well defined, aka does not depends on the decomposition of an element as a sum of elementary tensors), it is better to use the universal property of tensor products: the map $b:(f,a)\in K[T]\times F\mapsto af\in F[T]$ is $K$-bilinear, hence induces a $K$-linear map $\varphi: K[T]\otimes F\to F[T]$ which maps $f\otimes a$ to $af$.

You still have to prove that $\varphi$ is a $K$-algebra morphism. Clearly, it sends $1\otimes1 $ to $1$, and it remains to show that $\varphi$ respects the product, that is $$\varphi((\sum_{k=1}^n f_i\otimes a_i)(\sum_{\ell=1}^mg_i\otimes b_i))=\varphi(\sum_{k=1}^n f_i\otimes a_i)\varphi(\sum_{\ell=1}^mg_i\otimes b_i),$$
knowing that $\varphi$ is $K$-linear and $\varphi(f\otimes a)=af$.
I leave it to you.

To prove that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, it is perhaps easier to find the inverse. I let you check that the map $\psi: \sum_n a_n T^n\in F[T]\mapsto \sum_n T^n\otimes a_n$
 is a $K$-algebra morphism, and is an inverse of $\varphi$.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a bit confused by the notation (and tensor products in general...). If you have time, could you check if the following is the correct way of writing things down?
$\psi(\varphi(\sum_{i=0}^{n}(f_i\otimes a_i)))=\psi(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_if_i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\psi(a_if_i)=\sum_{i=0}^n(\sum_{j=0}^{m}(T_i^{j}\otimes a_{i_j})) = \sum_{i=0}^n(f_i\otimes a_i)$